# How do I push child object based on parent key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to push child object values based on parent key

Sample code :

```
let parent = {}
    let newobj = {}

    function setData(pid, cid, val) {
    //    let newobj = {}
        newobj[cid] = val;         
        parent[pid] = newobj;    
    }

    setData(1, 0, true)
    setData(1, 1, false)
    setData(0, 1, true)

    console.log(parent)
```

Expected output would be :

```
{
    0: {1: true},
    1: {0: true, 1: false}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reuse the existing object of the parent when it exists

```js
let parent = {}

function setData(pid, cid, val) {
  let newobj = parent[pid] || {};
  newobj[cid] = val;
  parent[pid] = newobj;
}

setData(1, 0, true)
setData(1, 1, false)
setData(0, 1, true)

console.log(parent)
```

---

Or if using es6 you can *spread* the object and update it in a single go

```js
let parent = {}

function setData(pid, cid, val) {
  parent[pid] = {
            ...parent[pid],
            [cid]: val
            }
}

setData(1, 0, true)
setData(1, 1, false)
setData(0, 1, true)

console.log(parent)
```

(*although this will create a new object each time*)

Comment: Learned the good and new thing today again, more than saying you saved my Day!!